# If condition not working in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to put if else condition in mysql trigger but it's giving error
here I have removed else query from my code is there any mistake here is there any alternate method 
my code -

```
IF(new.job_number= '1') 
THEN
  update prod_jobs 
  set job_time_L = (SELECT sum(job_time) 
                    FROM `jobs` 
                    WHERE job_number=new.job_number) 
  where job_number=new.job_number
ELSE
  insert into prod_jobs ('', '', '') 
  values ('','','')

END IF
```

[screen_shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjlSv.png)

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: `;`'s might help... and if your trigger is on prod_jobs, MySql won't allow this trigger at all.

Comment: @ollie #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: @Uueerdo my trigger is on job and where should place ;

Comment: Every query in mysql must be terminated by `;` (unless `;` has been overridden with another string). So after your update statement and insert statement (the ends of line 7 and 10 in the screenshot).